# Convert JSON into TXT format in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, aws-lambda

We use a handy `JSON` module called gsjson to convert Google Sheet data to JSON. I need to get a sheet listed as a list of URLs in TXT format instead.

I have tried changing the extension, but it just outputs as JSON format. How can I convert this into a list of plain text (excluding the header), listing the URLs, line by line?

```
// Create JSON file from Google Sheet and place in tmp
gsjson({
    spreadsheetId: sheetid ,
    credentials: 'mycreds.json'
})
.then(function(result) {
    result = JSON.stringify(result);
    fs.writeFile("/tmp/" + company +".json", result, 'utf-8', function (err) {
        if (err) console.log('Google Sheet written to tmp JSON - FAILED'); // an error occurred
        else     console.log('Google Sheet written to tmp JSON - SUCCESS');           // successful response
});
```

Current JSON Output

`[{"url":"https://example.com"},{"url":"https://examples.com"}]`

Desired TXT Output

`https://example.com
https://examples.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to `stringify` it, that'll convert it to JSON format, which doesn't make sense for what you're looking for. If you want just the `url` property from each item of the array, use `.map` to extract each property, and then join by newlines:

```
// ...
.then(function(result) {
  const textToWrite = result.map(({ url }) => url).join('\n');
  fs.writeFile("/tmp/" + company +".json", textToWrite, 'utf-8', function (err) {
  // ...
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that. Almost there, but the output comes out as ```https://example.comhttps://examples.com``` rather than on 2 lines

Comment: Er, really? I'm a bit doubtful, are you sure it's not just your editor? You did include the `.join('\n')`, right? I guess you can try `\r\n`, which Windows environments sometimes prefer

Comment: You're right, when I open it up in windows it comes out like that. But on S3 it outputs fine https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/githubgists/jsontotext.txt. So all good, ticked